# Can't close XBMC, on Ubuntu 13.04 x64

Tags: 13.04, freeze, workspaces, xbmc

All is well when I open XBMX (but even if I just open it by accident and I don't do anything in XBMC itself) When I try to close it (either via the 'x' at the top left to close the application, OR via the built-in menu) XBMC just hangs and will not quit unless I restart my machine (which is obviously a pain) - after I've asked to close with one of the ways mentioned the window becomes completely frozen and I can't do anything with it (apart from drag it from window to window or workspace to workspace, just so it's out the way)

And I then can't open another instance of XBMC either.

The only plug-ins I have are:
1Channel
Mashup
+any default/preloaded ones that I don't use

Anyone else having this issue?

Thanks, Jon

Comment: After doing some reading (I can't remember exactly where I read this but) - Someone mentioned that the pre-installed YouTube add on was buggy, I've just removed it (after watching a film on 1channel) - and tried to close XBMC via the menu and it closed no problem. - From that, it would seem that un-installing the youtube add-on fixes the issue I was having. Could you do the same and report back, see if that fix's it for you as well? - Cheers